# Accessing class element - a variable or array element?

Tags: php, object

How would I access the 14.95 here?

`$object->{0}` or `$object[0]` doesn't work

```
   SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [currencyID] => USD
            )

        [0] => 14.95
    )
```

Interesting... If I do `(int)$object->{0}` it works....

Comment: Hmm, my first instinct would be `$object->{'0'}`, and if that doesn't work a `var_dump(get_object_vars($object));` might make things more clear (never liked `print_r` for lack of data/type/length of hidden chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force it to be an integer: `(int)$object->{0}`

Answer (score 0):

Its bad practice to have numbers as properties of an object. Wouldn't a named property be easier to maintain?

**Edit**: I previously thought this wasn't actually possible however it looks like it is and instead leaves the code just a little ambiguous.

Comment: This happens when I pull from the eBay API, so I don't have a choice.